# ListActivity as StartActivity

Tags: android

Hy.

My startactivity should be a ListActivity.

```
public class Main extends ListActivity
```

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <ListView android:id="@+id/listView1" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"></ListView>
```

Everytime i start the app it crashs.

Please help

Logs:

```
09-22 16:37:35.115: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(349): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
09-22 16:37:35.129: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(349): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.korn.pizzacounter/com.korn.pizzacounter.Main}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
09-22 16:37:35.129: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(349):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2496)
09-22 16:37:35.129: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(349):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
09-22 16:37:35.129: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(349):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
09-22 16:37:35.129: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(349):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
09-22 16:37:35.129: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(349):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-22 16:37:35.129: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(349):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
09-22 16:37:35.129: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(349):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
09-22 16:37:35.129: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(349):     at Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
```

Comment: There is not enough information to answer your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's an ListActivity your default list must be called like this:

```
<ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
```

See developer documentation
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html

Answer (score 0):

use  this `android:id="@android:id/listView1` instead of `android:id="@+id/listView1`

in case listactivity of you must declare id like this

Answer (score 0):

```
at Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
```

If you are extending the ListActivity you should not use the `setContentView(R.layout.main)`.

So remove setContentView(R.layout.main) from your code.